# nodejs clustering and kill processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I found a tutorial that demonstrates clustering in node.js

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < npmCpu; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Process ${process.pid}, ${port} ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
  });
}
```

This is the first part. So if there `npmCpu` is 8. This will create 8 instances of the node application as I understood.

But the second part for a sample controller he added the process kill part.

```
app.get('/usersList',(req,res)=>{
//code..
res.status(200).json(users);
cluster.worker.kill();

})
```

And then up a new worker for that cluster like this

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < npmCpu; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
cluster.on('exit',(worker,code,signal)=>{
 cluster.fork();
})
} else {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Process ${process.pid}, ${port} ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
  });
}
```

This part was tricky. Why kill the worker at the end of the function?
What will happen if don't kill?

If we do clustering do we need to kill the process at the end of each and every controller in the express app?

Comment: Read this carefully it might answer your question 
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works 
Read carefully and lets discuss it

Comment: I think it just a conceptional thing, as in parallel programming the worker or sub-process are should be created to do a certain task send the results or make whatever side effect and kill itself.

Comment: It's obvious in the docs here: 
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_exit
That the exit events consider exited worker without signal or error code consider as  success worker

Comment: That's what  `cluster.worker.kill();` actually dose.
It just "gracefully disconnect the worker process" 

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_kill_signal